# How to call a javascript function in ejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I've tried adding an onclick function to my ejs button but it's not calling the function in my index.js.
here is my ejs button in the views folder

```
<button onclick="test();">test</button>
```

here is my index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();



const ejs = require('ejs'); //to connect to ejs files
const path = require('path'); //to use redirect and render
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs'); //specify engine



app.get('/', (req, res) => {        
  res.render("index")
})

function test() //here is the function I want called.
  {
    console.log("works")
  }


app.listen(3000)
```

How do I call a function from ejs? If it is not possible, then how do you change varibles? ex. pg+=1. So the pg in the link increases by 1.

Comment: That is not possible (a long explanation short). The application you have written (index.js) will render your ejs file and send it as a response to the client (browser). Calling JavaScript function etc. in the browser is something different. First read about ejs and how you use that and then go and read about how JavaScript is working in the browser -- two different things!

Answer (score -1):

In ejs or any technology, we cannot call a function front-end side which is declared in back-end(Server side).
For that you have to send a http request to the server.

Or if you want to call `test()` for onclick then you have to make a one script file and declare that function in that file. and load that script file using `<script src="YOUR FILE PATH"></script>`

After that you can call a test function on click.